# portgresql server version 10 - FATAL: password authentication failed for user "postgres"

Tags: java, spring, windows, postgresql

I'm trying to open a web application in the browser with Tomcat. But when I debug or start Tomcat, I get this error. The database username in the `web.xml` file in the Dynamic Web Project and in PostgreSQL is already "postgres". 
I get:

> "HTTP Status 404" error

when I run the server. I do not understand why it's making this mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Don't Set Password for PostgreSQL, leave it empty and it will solve your problem.

Comment: If it will work for you please vote and mark it as a right answer thanks